# D3.js graph not showing updated data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3.js project that includes radar charts that update gradually with an animation(code mostly based on Jorge Sancha's block [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jorgesancha/3a606cfcc250d26974311b2bab2d7c59)). I've currently created the function that will create the chart with an animation from the previous state(set of values) and intended state, and it works fine given the two desired sets of data.

However, when I try to update it dynamically after the first call (i.e. with a button click), the function won't update the graph.

I've looked this up and I believe that this is due to selectAll().data().enter() not updating previously bound data, and I tried to work with solutions that I found but wasn't particularly successful. I've also tried running exit().remove() on the update call but it didn't work?

Here's my code: it receives 'nextdata' (data to be displayed) and 'prevdata' (data from which the animation starts) and updates the polygon and circles that correspond to the data. The code itself works fine the first time - it's the updating that's an issue

```
function updateRadar(nextdata, prevdata = zerovalues, transitionTime = 1000) {
  var areas = radar.selectAll('polygon.area')
    .data([nextdata]).enter();

  areas.append('polygon')
    .classed('area', true)
    .attr('points', function () { //starting set of points for animation
      let prevpoints = new Array();
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        prevpoints.push(X(j, measureScale(prevdata[j].value)) + "," + Y(j, measureScale(prevdata[j].value)));
      }
      prevpoints.join(' ');
      return prevpoints;
    })
    .merge(areas)
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionTime)
    .attr('points', function (d) { //desired set of points (end result)
      return d.map(function (d, i) {
        var rad = measureScale(d.value);
        return [X(i, rad), Y(i, rad)];
      }).join(' ');
    });

  var points = radar.selectAll('circle.point')
    .data(nextdata).enter();

    points.append('circle')
    .classed('point', true)
    .attr('r', 7)
    .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
      return X(i, measureScale(prevdata[i].value));
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
      return Y(i, measureScale(prevdata[i].value));
    })
    .merge(points)
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionTime)
    .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
      return X(i, measureScale(d.value))
    })
    .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
      return Y(i, measureScale(d.value))
    });
}
```

This is the code I am trying to run but isn't working after one initial load.

```
updateRadar(data[1], data[0]);
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/dhxfrw3y/) is the full code - the desired behavior is the data updating to the next set when the button is clicked.

I'm relatively new to D3 so I might be doing something horribly wrong : help would be greatly appreciated!